# will the Windows 7 upgrade edition deactivate my XP key?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, upgrade

I have an upgrade edition copy of win7 from my university, but if I use it on my XP machine - will I lose access to that XP key?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It does not make sense.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but may be useful to you, a nice video on how to upgrade to W7 from XP...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7?T1=tab01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade edition is basically this: they check for your WinXP key in your WinXP install and if it exists it uses the Win7 key to install.

So you *can* still use XP, but contractually, you cannot have both installed at once (anywhere).

Think of it like having a locked door with two locks. You need both keys to open the Windows 7 door.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "upgrade install" from Windows XP to Windows 7. You must complete a "fresh/custom install". You can however run the Windows Easy Transfer Wizard and let it copy your personal files to a DVD/External media such as external harddrive or USB flashdrive.